# Where is the docker container data stored on the host machine?

Tags: docker, docker-container

In docker, where is the container data, apart from the mounted volume, is stored till the container is running.

So lets say /usr/local is volume mounted, so it would be shared between the host and the container. Where is everything else stored?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should inspect your docker container

```
docker inspect [ID_CONTAINER]
```

and check for the fields `MergedDir`, `LowerDir` and `UpperDir`. Docker uses **OverlayFS** file system to store the data.

> OverlayFS layers two directories on a single Linux host and presents them as a single directory. These directories are called layers and the unification process is referred to a a union mount. OverlayFS refers to the lower directory as lowerdir and the upper directory a upperdir. The unified view is exposed through its own directory called merged.
>   [image]

Check the doc [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#how-the-overlay-driver-works).

Comment: Did you meant `docker inspect [ID_CONTAINER]`?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command to get container written data

```
ll `podman inspect ContainerName --format "{{ .GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir }}"`
```